# Unable to Load NGINX pages on mobile Devices

Tags: networking, webserver, nginx

Server Overview:

- Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 running LEMP.
- Installed Ajenti V.
- Setup DDNS for my domain to point to my router IP.

Able to view it from my machine and from the outside world, but when i try to load it up on my iPhone from inside the network and from outside the network I cannot get it to load.

I have tried to do some research on this, however, I don't see other posts with the same or similar problems which means this is not a typical problem.

Nothing has changed on my server except updating web files.

I have also tried this on my Dad's android and I get the same result.

Why would it work on PC but not when its on a mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after spending several hours tracing this down.

Awhile ago I was trying to use a Dynamic DNS service that had me install a web based program. It was using apache2 not NGINX which meant that it had to work together. Luckily Ajenti defaulted everything to NGINX and I didn't have to do anything.

When I changed DDNS providers, I uninstalled everything related. Apache2, BIND9, and all the config files. However, one remained. It was an index file that was marked hidden so I couldn't see it normally without "Viewing Hidden Files". Since I don't normally log into the server, I just use its samba share I almost would have never caught it.

Even though it was hidden, my server still used it and redirected mobile devices to a blank page hence why it wasn't loading. Once removed everything became 900% better.